# Admob banner, on google map activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I would like to show a banner ad on my map activities everything I have tried fails.
And I can't seem to find any posts on the topic.
My mapActivity.xml
Below.
sorry very new

ERRORS in logcat
2022-01-12 08:09:40.030 22190-22190/com.app.hotspringsofbc I/MainActivity: deserializeUserMaps
2022-01-12 08:09:51.719 22190-22190/com.app.hotspringsofbc I/MapsAdapter: Tapped on position 6
2022-01-12 08:09:51.724 10144-10995/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.app.hotspringsofbc/.DisplayMapActivity (has extras)} from uid 10080 on display 0
2022-01-12 08:09:52.762 22190-22190/com.app.hotspringsofbc I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
2022-01-12 08:09:52.768 22190-22190/com.app.hotspringsofbc I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 202414022
2022-01-12 08:09:52.950 22190-22190/com.app.hotspringsofbc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.hotspringsofbc, PID: 22190
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.hotspringsofbc/com.app.hotspringsofbc.DisplayMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment. View com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{8d5535 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0046 app:id/adView} is not associated with a Fragment.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment. View com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{8d5535 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0046 app:id/adView} is not associated with a Fragment.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment. View com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{8d5535 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0046 app:id/adView} is not associated with a Fragment.
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.addView(FragmentContainerView.java:309)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4267)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at com.app.hotspringsofbc.databinding.ActivityDisplayMapBinding.inflate(ActivityDisplayMapBinding.java:49)
at

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:id="@+id/map" 
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   tools:context=".DisplayMapActivity" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9999999999999-9999999"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: you could wrap fragmentcontainerview with a relative layout and add the adView below of the fragmentcontainview.

Answer (score 0):

For AdMob Banner you should add view to your Activity or Fragment:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

[Here's the full documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

**EDITED**

How I usually implement Admob Banners:

```
public class BannerAdLogic {
    private Context context;
    private AdView mAdView;

    public BannerAdLogic(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void initializeBanner(View fragmentView) {
        if (!((WiFiDirectActivity) context).isUserPremium()) {
//            MobileAds.initialize(context, initializationStatus -> {
//
//            });

            mAdView = new AdView(context);
            mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER);
            mAdView.setAdUnitId(AdsConstants.getBannerId(context));

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            ((RelativeLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rl_adView)).addView(mAdView); //uncomment this

            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            adListeners();
        }
    }

    private void adListeners() {
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError adError) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Some layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in Fragment onViewCreated send view to banner's class.

Comment: I can't get it to allow me to just place it. I do have banner ads working in other places in the app. I just can't get it to work in this view.

Comment: @KushGuy okay, so add some code how you add your banner and a working example 'cause we can't know how you implement banners. and format your code please. maybe you have some errors or something?

Comment: @KushGuy and check maybe your fragment inside this layout is match_parent so you just can't see the banner

Comment: i updated my code to look like what i have had ( 1 of the attempts ).
 as soon as i change the map from the fragment app crashes on click to open map

Comment: @KushGuy can you provide error message when it crashes?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , no i cant but ill be sure to recreate it today and will

Comment: @KushGuy I edited my answer with a fully working code I usually use for this purpose, maybe it will help you

Comment: @KushGuy as I can see you add Banner to FragmentContainerView, that's the problem. try to create a Layout in which will be your FragmentContainerView and AdMob banner.

Comment: yea thats where i been at for a day :) but no matter the container i add it to it will error ... although im sure new and am likely doing it all wrong

Comment: @KushGuy how do you attach your fragment? inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false) ?

Comment: I think you can try to remove AdView from here and add it to your fragment layout where you keep all your views and it will resolve your problem

Comment: its my first project with zero history in coding so bear with me :) i think what you are referrig to is my mapsAdapter.kt ? 
 i have attached a link to my project https://github.com/ipodguy79/Google_maps_clone_with_WebView

Comment: nothing seems to work i cant touch the xml for this activity it just fails, 
and now 15 tutorials in and not one of them has worked either, nor has anyone got a answer to this question in the last 5 years that i can find

Comment: @KushGuy I can't see any crashes and any banners as well